# Netty not start on the vps

Tags: java, netty

I can’t listen to port 1616 and all others on my VPS server using Netty. When typing the address xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:1616 there is no answer, if I run server on my computer, everything is perfectly listened to, the vps server is not. The sad thing is that when I run a project on a VPS using mvc, it does not give any errors, it seems that everything works well. I'm just starting to learn netty.

**ChatServer.java**

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;


public class ChatServer {
    private final int port;
    ChatServer(int port){
        this.port=port;
    }
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup=new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup=new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try{
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap=new ServerBootstrap().group(bossGroup,workerGroup).option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true).childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).childHandler(new ChatServerIntializer());
            bootstrap.bind("localhost",port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("End.");
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting..");
        System.out.println("1.3");
        new ChatServer(1616).run();
    }
}
```

**ChatServerHandler.java**

```
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor;

class ChatServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
    private static final ChannelGroup channels=new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, String s) throws Exception {
        Channel incoming=channelHandlerContext.channel();
        for(Channel channel : channels){
            channel.writeAndFlush("["+incoming.remoteAddress()+"]"+" write: "+s);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Channel incoming=ctx.channel();
        for(Channel channel : channels){
            if(incoming==channel){
                continue;
            }
            channel.writeAndFlush("["+incoming.remoteAddress()+"]"+" join in the chat");
        }
        channels.add(ctx.channel());
        super.handlerAdded(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Channel incoming=ctx.channel();
        for(Channel channel : channels){
            channel.writeAndFlush("["+incoming.remoteAddress()+"]"+" exit from the chat");
        }
        channels.remove(ctx.channel());
        super.handlerRemoved(ctx);
    }




}
```

**ChatServerIntializer.java**

```
package com.app;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;

class ChatServerIntializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline=socketChannel.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder",new StringEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("handler",new ChatServerHandler());
    }
}
```

This is all I start with the command `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.app.ChatServer"`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOTXj.png

I would like to find a solution or possible reasons

Comment: You bind the server to `localhost`, this means that you can only connect from `localhost`, I assume this is not intentional?

Comment: @FerrybigI tried to do without localhost, and write only the port. I also tried to write ip server instead of localhost. In both cases, nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got that!**

Turning off the firewall helped me

````
$ sudo iptables -t nat -F
$ sudo iptables -t nat -X
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -F
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -X
$ sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT```
````